# sbt: suppressing logging prefix in stdout

Tags: scala, logging, sbt

When using sbt with forking (`fork in run := true`), every output from my application to stdout is prefixed by `[info]`; output to stderr is prefixed with `[error]`.

This behavior is somewhat annoying when using a Java logging framework which outputs to stderr. The resulting debug messages typically look like this:

```
[error] [main] INFO MyClass ...
[error] [main] DEBUG MyClass ...
```

I would like to suppress these prefixes like when running the code without forking. What I tried:

- setting `sbt -Dsbt.log.noformat=true` in the sbt launch script. But this only removes colored ANSI output; prefixes are still there just without color
- setting `logLevel in run := Level.Error` in `build.sbt`. This does not seem to have any influence on logging with forking.

Is there any way to suppress the prefixes?

Comment: I'm curious about this too.

Comment: Found it! I tracked down the source for how SBT launches processes: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/run/src/main/scala/sbt/Fork.scala. And then I simply searched some keywords from that file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set the [output strategy](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking#configuring-output) of your project.

In my extended build I have the following settings:

```
settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
  fork                  :=   true, // Fork to separate process
  connectInput in run   :=   true, // Connects stdin to sbt during forked runs
  outputStrategy        :=   Some(StdoutOutput) // Get rid of output prefix
  // ... other settings
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks like the output strategy is a new feature of 0.13? Iirc, I did not see anything regarding output strategy in 0.12.

Comment: Yes, I just had time to experiment with it. Works perfectly!

Comment: Is it just me or is this now broken in 0.13.11?

Comment: I tried this with sbt 1.3.8 and 1.4.4, but whatever setting I enter it doesn't seem to make a different.

Answer (score 0):

Can do

```
sbt -error ...
```

and also

```
sbt -warn ...
```