# Scala sbt: How to turn off [info] messages for `~run`?

Tags: scala, sbt

When using `~run` I don't want to see `[info]` messages.

I have tried `sbt -error` and `set logLevel := Level.Error` but the `[info]` messages are still emitted.

This question is similar to [How to suppress info and success messages in sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968300/how-to-suppress-info-and-success-messages-in-sbt). However the solution there works only for `sbt run` whereas this question is about `~run` issued after starting sbt in interactive mode (`sbt -error`).

Answer (score 0):

I found a half of solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16676014/4050580 .
To apply this only for `run` command use:

```
  run / outputStrategy := Some(StdoutOutput)
```